# Rails REST put using Firefox RESTclient

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to test REST input into a Rails 3 application.  I'm using Firefox add-on called RESTclient.  For staters, I'm just trying to PUT (Update) one column in a the database (contact2="Bart").

I get back 200, but the **column doesn't get updated in the database** and the response shows the column to still contain "Mary2"

Here's a pic:

[image]

This is the controller:

```
  # PUT /workorders/1
  # PUT /workorders/1.json
  def update
    @workorder = Workorder.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @workorder.update_attributes(params[:workorder])
        format.html { redirect_to @workorder, notice: 'Workorder was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render json: @workorder }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @workorder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Rails Log:

```
Started PUT "/workorders/56673.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-17 14:40:30 -0700
  [1m[35mWostatus Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "wostatuses".* FROM "wostatuses" ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 1
Processing by WorkordersController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"56673"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  [1m[36mWorkorder Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "workorders".* FROM "workorders" WHERE "workorders"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "56673"]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Completed 200 OK in 143ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Is the parameter "contact2" not being sent?

Comment: Okay. What steps have you taken to debug it? What are you seeing in the Rails log? Is the correct controller action being called? Is it receiving the params you expect? What does your controller code look like? Do the variables in your controller have the values you expect on each line? Are the methods you expect to be called called and are the `if`/`else` branches you expect to be taken taken? How are you testing whether or not the database has been updated? Are you sure you're fetching the same record, and that the data you're looking at is current?

Comment: I updated my question. Also, I'm looking at the database with PGAdmin to see if it got update.  Plus, the RESTclient show the response - which contains json for the updated record.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using Wiztools RESTclient.

I had to use:

Body = application/json; charset=UTF-8
 {
    "contact2": "Bart"
 }